# how to show that $ \ln (x^2 e^{-x(a-1)}+1) = O(x^2e^{-x(a-1)}) $

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I found this strange result from a solved exercise: (with $x\to\infty$ and $a>1$)

$$  \ln (x^2 e^{-x(a-1)}+1) = O(x^2e^{-x(a-1)})  $$

I cannot explain how to get this, I can only think of using Taylor series,
I tried Maclaurin expansion of logarithm:
$$   \ln (1+x) = x +o(x)$$
I can use this because if $x\to\infty$ and $a>1$ then $x^2 e^{-x(a-1)}\rightarrow 0 $, so I get:

$$ \ln (x^2 e^{-x(a-1)}+1) = x^2e^{-x(a-1)} + o(x^2e^{-x(a-1)}) $$

How can I arrive to $O(x^2e^{-x(a-1)})$ ? Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t}{ln(t+1)}=1$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1055851)

Comment: you are suggesting to get the result using the definition of big O itself, interesting, tanks!

Comment: @Arnaud D, this is not an answer but it is a hint that helps to solve the question. I always think it is better to give hints.